# How to make Unified FFI work in Pharo

Tags: pharo

I have a C function that copies a string into a buffer that's been passed to it:

```
void get_machine(char *buf) {
    /* do something to acquire the machine string */
    strcpy(buf, machine_string);
}
```

I want to call it from Pharo:

```
machine := String new: 256.
self ffiCall: #( void get_machine(String machine) ) module: 'ffilibc.so'.
```

But this doesn't work: the contents of machine_string do not get copied into machine. What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

I learned that the String buffer is immutable. That's why the C function couldn't write to it.

The solution is to use a ByteArray.

Comment: and then use #asString on it. (or #asWideString if the case arises)

Answer (score 2):

"It does not work" is too vague. Can you tell me what's your error?

in case is "module not found", this is because you need to give the full path (unless library is in same place as the image). Also remember the library needs to be compiled for 32bits.

Comment: Sorry, I meant that the contents of machine_string fail to be copied into the buffer. All I get are 256 spaces.

Comment: Just to be on the safe side: are you sure that the C function does what you think it does? Are you sure it doesn't receive an empty string?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. I wrote a simple C program to test the C library.